# why size of kivy ` s widget isn`t real?

Tags: python, kivy

there is my code:

```
class MyGame(Widget):
    def prepare_game(self):
        print(self.height, self.width)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = MyGame()
        game.prepare_game()
        return game

MyApp().run()
```

Output is 100 100, but it isn`t really so. Can I find out the actual size of the widget when I want to call method prepare_game() once?

Comment: What does 'Output is 100 100, but it isn`t really so.' mean?  What is the output?

Comment: I meant the values outputted by the function print(). Real size of widget isn't 100x100 pixels. Sorry, my english isn't well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in your above example the size of the widget isn't set. And when that is the case you will get the default size which is 100, 100. The updated size can always be found through `on_size` method as shown in the following example.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyGame(Widget):        
    def prepare_game(self):
        print(self.height, self.width)

    def on_size(self, *args):
        print(self.size)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = MyGame()
        game.prepare_game()
        return game

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I would use my app on smartphone and setting window/'s size manually... Isn't conveniently. Can I know real size without this?

Comment: One way to do it in ```on_size``` method. With this method you will get the updated size whenever you set the size.